# Dell LCD display icons/screen is fuzzy

Tags: display

I have an LCD dell screen with driver: ATI Radeon HD 4300/4500 Series

The screen has been working fine, but the icons currently appear fuzzy and the screen is a bit brighter than it used to be.

Last thing i was doing on my pc was trying to delete Baidu antivirus from the Registry. The next day the screen became messed up this way. I'm not sure I might have deleted a driver component or so.

I used the AMD system detect and installed an updated driver and restarted my pc, but it's still the same.

Comment: How's it connected to the GPU?

Comment: Assuming your using Windows, have you tried [System Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/system-restore) to a date prior to the issue?